# Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION Invalid vote type '5-star(db=6,api=5)'

Tags: apex, soql, dml, knowledge

```
  //This method is used to upsert an vote for article 
@AuraEnabled 
public static String upsertVote(Id voteId, String kbId, String val){
    System.debug('voteId::'+voteId);
    System.debug('kbId::'+kbId);
    System.debug('val::'+val);
    String result;
    Knowledge__ka parentKnowledge=new Knowledge__ka(); //to get the Id for vote parent Object
    Try{
    //get the article number
    List<Knowledge__kav> knowledge = [Select Id,ArticleNumber From Knowledge__kav Where Id=:kbId];
    if(knowledge.size() > 0){
        System.debug('knowledge.ArticleNumber::'+knowledge[0].ArticleNumber);
        if(knowledge[0].ArticleNumber != null){
            parentKnowledge = [SELECT Id FROM Knowledge__ka Where ArticleNumber =:knowledge[0].ArticleNumber];            
        }
    }
    System.debug('parentKnowledge.Id::'+parentKnowledge.Id);
    if(parentKnowledge.Id != null && val != null){
        Vote v=new Vote();
        if(voteId != null){
            v.Id = voteId;
        }else{ 
            v.ParentId = parentKnowledge.Id;
        }
        v.type = val;
        System.debug('v::'+v);
        upsert v;
        result = v.Id;
    }
    }Catch(Exception e){
        system.debug('Exception Cause::'+e.getCause());
        system.debug('Exception LineNumber::'+e.getLineNumber());
        system.debug('Exception Message::'+e.getMessage());
        system.debug('Exception StackTrace::'+e.getStackTraceString());
        system.debug('Exception TypeName::'+e.getTypeName());  
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

My code is working fine in my salesforce one of the sandbox (dev) and i pushed the code to another sandbox for testing  i am getting the error. The above is the method which was used to do an dml operation on vote object for the knowledge article. But when i tring to upsert/Inset an vote i am getting the following the error msg below:

> Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Invalid vote type '5-star(db=6,api=5)' for
> voting mode 'UP_DOWN(db=0,api=UpDown)'.: Vote Type: [Type]

Can some one help me on this.

Comment: Usually field exceptions are thrown when you have validation rule or a field is required and not satisfied. Try to check the value of Type field if it’s in the right format.

Comment: yes i have checked the type field the values is in right format

Comment: For Upsert operation you’ll also need to add an external Id as a second parameter

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have find out the issue caused.

Answer (score 4):

For the lightning Knowledge base the Vote type will be 1 to 5. For the classic KB the vote type is UP or Down. If you are using lightning disable the option
'Enable thumbs up or down voting for article (Classic Only)' in Knowledge Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. i have find out the issue caused. –
Vinod
Dec 14, 2021 at 10:04

- Could you let us know what cause the issue?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/177816)